# Django+Apache+Virtualenv+WSGI(Can not change the primary interpreter)

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, wsgi

I have virtualenv with python 2.7.3 and any site-packages.
On this server - python 2.6.6. I need python 2.7.3 as the main interpreter

wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys
import site


# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project')
sys.path.append('/var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project/mts_report_project')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mts_report_project.settings.local'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env="/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/bin/activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mail
        ServerName server_name
        ServerAlias alias_name
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project
        WSGIDaemonProcess mts_report processes=1 maximum-requests=1 threads=1 python-path=/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7:/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup mts_report
        WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project/wsgi.py

        Alias /static/ /var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project/static/
        Alias /home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin/media/
        <Directory /var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project>
            Options +Indexes
            allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/servicescripts_error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/servicescripts_access.log combined
        <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Check python version(on debug django mode):

```
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project',
 '/var/www/mts_report/mts_report_project/mts_report_project']
```

As a result, Django use site-packages from virtualenv, but main interpreter - from system.
How use interpreter(2.7.3) from virtualenv?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday the problem was solved.
Useful to those who have encountered a similar problem.
**mod_vsgi was not compiled for python 2.7.**
Thank you all for your answers.

First, **install apache2-threaded-dev**
Then, **compile PYTHON with --enable-shared**. This is important.

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/python-2.7.3
make
make install
ln -s /usr/local/python-2.7.3/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7.3
```

**libpython2.7.so.1.0 not found** problem:

```
ln -s /usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so /usr/
```

**compile MOD_WSGI with python2.7.3**:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7.3
make
make install
```

restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

In apache config add at the beginning

```
WSGIPythonHome PATH_TO_YOUR_2.7.3_PYTHON

<VirtualHost *:80>
...
```

Note you may have to also add something like

```
WSGISocketPrefix ../../var/run/wsgi
```

Also change

```
python-path=/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7:/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

to

```
python-path=/home/aaodegov/virtual_envs/basic_env_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and you don't need references to virtualenv in wsgi.py

Comment: If mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6, you cannot do this. You would need to install mod_wsgi such that it is compiled against Python 2.7. Only then could you refer to a specific Python virtual environment using Python 2.7.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed mod_wsgi was compiled by Python 2.7. Graham is having just mod_wsgi compiled by Python 2.7 sufficient to use correct version of Python. It didn't work for me. I had to still use WSGIPythonHome PATH_TO_YOUR_2.7.3_PYTHON. I have several Python installations and Python 33 + Apache 2.2

Comment: If Python 2.7 is installed in a non standard location such as /usr/local, then yes you can still need to set WSGIPythonHome as it will otherwise fallback to using /usr as prefix as it will find /usr/bin/python. The interpreter is a bit stupid. The 'python' executable isn't used for an embedded system, but it uses it as reference point to work out where prefix and thus lib directory is.

Comment: Thanks Graham. Yes I had all Python installed from /opt/. Not sure where Sasha has his Python installed. I assumed he has Python somewhere else then /usr/ and his problem is similar to my.

Comment: Their primary issue is that it is showing that the Python version is 2.6 anyway. That has to be resolved first.